# Check Files Is Exists In Folder With Timers

Tags: c#

I need help with C#, the question is how can I check if a .txt file exists in a folder using the timer counter, if the file already exists the counter will be stopped and attached. the message that the file is available, i ask the timer to check the folder continuously if the file already exists, the timer will stop, thanks

I hope someone will help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To help with a first attempt: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/check-if-a-file-exists-in-chash https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution to your question.

```
DateTime DT_Start = DateTime.UtcNow;
bool FileIsFound = false;
const int ONESEC = 1000;
string Path = @"C:\Users\Schecher_1\Desktop";
string FileName = "test.txt";

while (!FileIsFound)
{
    FileIsFound = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, FileName).Any();
    Thread.Sleep(ONESEC);
}

Console.WriteLine($"The File {FileName} was found! " +
                  $"{Environment.NewLine}" +
                  $"{(DT_Start - DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")} were needed!");
```

Comment: Path and filename must of course still be changed at the top.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
var isFileExists = false;
while (!isFileExists)
{
   isFileExists = Directory.EnumerateFiles("directoryToSearch", "*.txt").Any();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.WriteLine("File found!");
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(...)` returns *all* (possibly *very many*) files; `Directory.EnumerateFiles("directoryToSearch", "*.txt").Any();` stops on the *very first* file found

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks. I am going to edit answer then :)

Comment: please tell me why var isFilesExist must be false? , if so will the while function be disabled?